# Write and read raw byte arrays in Spark - using Sequence File SequenceFile

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark, sequencefile

How do you write `RDD[Array[Byte]]` to a file using Apache Spark and read it back again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Common problems seem to be getting a weird cannot cast exception from BytesWritable to NullWritable.  Other common problem is BytesWritable `getBytes` is a totally pointless pile of nonsense which doesn't get bytes at all.  What `getBytes` does is get your bytes than adds a ton of zeros on the end!  You have to use `copyBytes`

```
val rdd: RDD[Array[Byte]] = ???

// To write
rdd.map(bytesArray => (NullWritable.get(), new BytesWritable(bytesArray)))
  .saveAsSequenceFile("/output/path", codecOpt)

// To read
val rdd: RDD[Array[Byte]] = sc.sequenceFile[NullWritable, BytesWritable]("/input/path")
  .map(_._2.copyBytes())
```

Comment: This post is relatively old so just wanted to know whether the answer is still up to date? Is it still necessary to use copyBytes before reading?

Comment: @SamStoelinga Yes I think so, it's Hadoop API that is unlikely to change.

Comment: A more efficient alternative is to use `<BytesWritableInstance>.getBytes()` and process only up to `<BytesWritableInstance>.getLength()` bytes. Of course, if you strictly need an `RDD[Array[Byte]]`, this approach won't work, but you could consider an `RDD[(Array[Byte], Int)]`.

Comment: Can anyone post an entire working code snippet including what packages to be imported? Thanks.

Comment: @Choix - I had the same issue.  Posting snippet that solved my problem as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with all required imports that you can run from spark-shell, as requested by @Choix

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable

val path = "/tmp/path"

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("foo"))
val bytesRdd = rdd.map{str  =>  (NullWritable.get, new BytesWritable(str.getBytes) )  }
bytesRdd.saveAsSequenceFile(path)

val recovered = sc.sequenceFile[NullWritable, BytesWritable]("/tmp/path").map(_._2.copyBytes())
val recoveredAsString = recovered.map( new String(_) )
recoveredAsString.collect()
// result is:  Array[String] = Array(foo)
```