# Decoded Snappy compressed byte arrays have trailing zeros

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, protocol-buffers, snappy

I am trying to write and read Snappy compressed byte array created from a protobuf from a Hadoop Sequence File.

The array read back from hadoop has trailing zeros. If a byte array is a small and simple removing trailing zeros is enough to parse the protobuf back, however for more complex objects and big sequence files parsing fails.

Byte array example:

```
val data = Array(1,2,6,4,2,1).map(_.toByte)
val distData = sparkContext.parallelize(Array.fill(5)(data))
  .map(j => (NullWritable.get(), new BytesWritable(j)))

distData
  .saveAsSequenceFile(file, Some(classOf[SnappyCodec]))

val original = distData.map(kv=> kv._2.getBytes).collect()

val decoded = sparkContext
  .sequenceFile[NullWritable, BytesWritable](file)
  .map( kv => kv._2.getBytes.mkString).collect().foreach(println(_))
```

Output:
original := 126421
decoded  := 126421000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem stems from `BytesWritable.getBytes`, which returns a backing array that may be longer than your data. Instead, call `copyBytes` (as in [Write and read raw byte arrays in Spark - using Sequence File SequenceFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083332/write-and-read-raw-byte-arrays-in-spark-using-sequence-file-sequencefile)).

See [HADOOP-6298: BytesWritable#getBytes is a bad name that leads to programming mistakes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6298) for more details.